# inserting image into spreadsheetGear excel

Tags: c#, excel, image, spreadsheetgear

I am using the below code to insert logo into my excel sheet but I am getting the excel without the image

```
double width;
double height;
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(logo);

using (image)
{
    width = image.Width * 72.0 / image.HorizontalResolution;
    height = image.Height * 72.0 / image.VerticalResolution;
}

SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheetWindowInfo windowInfo = sheet.WindowInfo;
double left = windowInfo.ColumnToPoints(1.5);
double top = windowInfo.RowToPoints(1.5);
sheet.Shapes.AddPicture(logo, left, top, width, height);
```

then I save the workbook as stream and return file

```
workbook.SaveToStream(memStream, SpreadsheetGear.FileFormat.OpenXMLWorkbook);
var mSream = new MemoryStream(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memStream.Length);

var FileDownloadName = string.Format("Report");

return File(mSream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", FileDownloadName);
```

Comment: I just put together a simple ASP.NET MVC app using your code above and, other than encountering a minor issue with the filename being "Report" without a file extension (I altered your FileDownloadName to be "Report.xlsx"), I was able to generate and download an Excel file with a picture embedded in it.  I used a PNG image off my computer as a test.  Can you provide more complete example that demonstrates the issue you are seeing?

Comment: actually it worked, I was editing the sheet our of context, worked fine after moving the code to other location